# how can i push a msgbox if record is not found in Database using vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

seeking help how i can push a msgbox error if a record is not in the database or no data in the database. im using vb.net and sql to check the record. not sure how to do,

here is my code

```vb
Try
    myConnection.Open()

    str = "SELECT * FROM tblEmp WHERE (EmpID = '" & ADS.UserEmpID & "')"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader    

    While dr.Read()
        'Main.BGCPnl.Visible = True
        BGC1 = dr("PreStartChecks").ToString
        BGC2 = dr("EmpName").ToString               

       //>Here is my code for the error message when record is not 
      found, im not sure what will be the right code. 
         i used count parameter

        BGCEmp = dr(ADS.UserEmpID)
        If BGCEmp.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("no record")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End While
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Unable to Connect to BGC DB. You may not have access or DB not available." & ex.ToString)
End Try

myConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Please don't include huge wads of empty space in your code.  It just makes it hard to read.  I have removed most of the blank lines.

Comment: I would also suggest that you take a look at the documentation for `ExecuteReader`.  It is overloaded and can accept a `CommandBehavior` value.  One of the possible values is `SingleRow` and you should use that to optimise your code is you are executing a query that can't retrieve more than one record.

Comment: Also, you should look into the `Using` keyword.  In your case, you should be creating your `OleDbConnection` object with a `Using` statement and then it will be implicitly closed at the `End Using` statement, even if an unhandled exception is thrown within the block.  You should always create and destroy short-lived, disposable objects that way.

Comment: Finally, you should always use parameters to insert values into SQL code.  String concatenation is far more error-prone, due to issues with readability and formatting.  Most importantly though, using parameters protects you from SQL injection.  In certain cases, a malicious user could delete the entire contents of your database by entering some SQL code where you expect only a value.  That is impossible if you use parameters.

Comment: @jmcilhinney if you are going to edit a question at least remove the irrelevent tags, its clear this question relates to VB.Net not VBScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining if a query returns 'no rows' in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088410/determining-if-a-query-returns-no-rows-in-vb-net)

Comment: Hi @Lankymart your reference have definitely solve my issue. very helpful. really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should learn how to properly use the `Read` method and the `HasRows` property of your data reader.  If there can never be more than one record but there might be none then use just `Read`:

```vb
If myDataReader.Read() Then
    'There is a row and you can access its data here.
Else
    'There are no rows.
End If
```

If there may be multiple rows and either there can't be no rows or you don't need to do anything specific in the case that there are no rows then just use `Read`:

```vb
While myDataReader.Read()
    'Access the current row here.
End While
```

If there are no rows then you never enter the loop and execution simply continues after that.

If there may be zero, one or more rows and you do need to do something specific in the case where there are none, use both `HasRows` and `Read`:

```vb
If myDataReader.HasRows Then
    'There is at least one row so read the data.
    While myDataReader.Read()
        'Access the current row here.
    End While
Else
    'There are no rows.
End If
```

There may be situations where you only care whether there is data but you don't need the data itself.  In that case, just use `HasRows`:

```vb
If myDataReader.HasRows Then
    'There is a at least one row
Else
    'There are no rows.
End If
```

In cases like that though, I'd suggest that you should be doing something like using a `COUNT` function in your query and calling `ExecuteScalar` rather than calling `ExecuteReader`.

Comment: Thank  you the reference you shared. i appreciate. i'l check all of this and apply it on my code.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Try
  myConnection.Open()

  str = "SELECT * FROM tblEmp WHERE (EmpID = '" & ADS.UserEmpID & "')"
  Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
  dr = cmd.ExecuteReader    
  If dr.HasRows Then
    While dr.Read()
      BGC1 = dr("PreStartChecks").ToString
      BGC2 = dr("EmpName").ToString               
    End While
  Else
    MessageBox.Show("No Record found", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Exit Sub
  End If
Catch ex As Exception
  MsgBox("Unable to Connect to BGC DB. You may not have access or DB not available." & ex.ToString)
End Try

myConnection.Close()
```

Read documentation about `Read()` and `HasRows`.

Comment: While this is not necessarily wrong, I'm not sure that it's optimal.  By the looks of the query and the code in the `While` loop, there can never be more than one match.  In that case, testing `HasRows` and then calling `Read` in a loop is suboptimal.  It would be better to get rid of the loop and test `Read` instead of `HasRows`.

Comment: Could do with some formatting, that indentation is horrendous to follow.