# How to check if a query returns a null value and add it to a label text?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am creating a new app in Windows Forms (vb.net) that checks if there are any records added on a daily basis to a SQL database, based on some criteria.
The issue is that I can't figure it out, how to display some message in a label box if the query returns a null value.

```
Public Sub LoadUser2()
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim Con = New SqlConnection("Server=my server;database=My db;Integrated Security = True")
    Con.Open()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("select sum(Minutes)/60 as 'Ore Logate' from [dbo].[UserActivity]
                                            where team = 'Xaver' and username like '%alnecula%' and Convert(date,DateCreated) = Convert(date,getdate())", Con)
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    da.Fill(dt)

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Txtgvlad.Text = "Logged Hours: " & dt.Rows(0)("Username").ToString
    Else
        Txtgvlad.Text = "You haven't logged any hours"
    End If
    Con.Close()
End Sub
```

Therefore i want to display the amount of hours logged if there are any, else display the string message which informs the user that there are no hours logged. Currently the code is showing me `Logged Hours:` if there is a null result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining if a query returns 'no rows' in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088410/determining-if-a-query-returns-no-rows-in-vb-net)

Comment: You should wrap your columns in `ISNULL`, this way you can return something... Change the query not the code... Also why would you be using `Username` as logged hours?

Comment: If you only want to read a single value use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`. There's no need to use SqlDataAdapter to create a table and only then read the actual value

Comment: @AdiPetrescu If you get it working whichever way you choose try using stored procedures instead of inline code queries. This will make it more efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your actual code is that even if the where condition don't return any record you still have a row in your table that contains a NULL. So your test is always true. You can test this simply copying your query in Sql Server Management Studio and running it.

Instead you could use ExecuteScalar to get the result

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("select sum(Minutes)/60 as 'Ore Logate' 
                                        from [dbo].[UserActivity]
                                        where team = 'Xaver'  
                                          and username like '%alnecula%' 
                                          and Convert(date,DateCreated) = Convert(date,getdate())", Con)
Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
If Not IsDBNull(result) Then 
    Txtgvlad.Text = "Logged Hours: " & result.ToString
Else
    Txtgvlad.Text = "You haven't logged any hours"
End If
```

Consider also that this query could return zero (but not a NULL) and, in this case the IF condition will be true. If you want to write the false message even in case of zero returned then you need to add a AndAlso condition to the If

```
If Not IsDBNull(result) AndAlso result.ToString <> "0" Then
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice way you could go about it would be to use a `sqldatareader`. so basically you do your Sp as usualy but execute it using the reader then you use `.hasrows` in a if statement. so for example with what you provided

```
Public Sub LoadUser2()

    Dim Con = New SqlConnection("Server=my server;database=My db;Integrated Security = True")
    Con.Open()
    Dim cmd As new SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("select sum(Minutes)/60 as 'Ore Logate' from [dbo].[UserActivity]
                                        where team = 'Xaver' and username like '%alnecula%' and Convert(date,DateCreated) = Convert(date,getdate())", Con)


   using RDR = cmd.executeReader
    if RDR.has rows
       IF RDR("YourColumnName").tostring() = "" then
          Txtgvlad.Text = "You haven't logged any hours"
       else
        Txtgvlad.Text = "Logged Hours: " & RDR("Username").ToString

    else
        Txtgvlad.Text = "You haven't logged any hours"
    end if
  end using


    Con.Close()
End Sub
```

The reason your original one may be still returning that it has rows might be because it is returning a row but just empty rows.

Comment: If only one value is expected it's better to use ExecuteScalar

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Don't have to but my version is a valid option. I agree executescalar is a good option just giving my 2 cents. Also if there is results instead of using a data table can read the "Username" straight from the database table

Comment: @K.Madden I have tried your approach, but once i run the code I get the following error: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Could not find stored procedure ''.'`

Comment: @AdiPetrescu Sorry i assumed you were using a stored procedure, see updated answer! Got rid of the `commandtype` and added in your actual query.

Comment: @K.Madden That worked, bu i had to use a `Try - Catch` sequence for that `If` statement, because the value returned by that query is sometimes null. So basically I need to figure out now how to display a message when the query result returns a null

Comment: You could add a `elseif` to the rdr such that `elseif rdr(name of any your columns in table).tostring() = "" then Txtgvlad.Text = "You haven't logged any hours"`